# Fire a tick once a day in go (golang) - Not by polling

Tags: performance, go, time

I am using go 1.14

I want to fire a tick once a day, but as far as I understand from the source code, the `Timer` functions are polling, and not waiting for some signals.

Is it true? and if so, what is the best way to fire an event once a day? The polling way looks to me very excessive.

Comment: Follow  https://godoc.org/time#example-Tick with duration `24 * time.Hour`.  The loop will execute once a day.

Comment: Sure that's work but i wonder if it is too much expensive, because i think the function is polling, and maybe there are other options.

Comment: Channel receive does not poll.

Comment: They don't, but the function that send that data to the channel is polling (as far as i understand).

Comment: Why do you think a runtime timer is polling and expensive to run once per day?

Answer (score 1):

The go source for [`time.NewTicker(...)`](https://golang.org/src/time/tick.go?s=706:740#L11) appears to use channels which are not implemented by polling, so you should be able to simply do the following:

```
t := time.NewTicker(24 * time.Hour)
for _ = range t.C {
    // ...
}
```

You could also use [`time.Sleep(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep):

```
for {
  // ...
  time.Sleep(24 * time.Hour)
}
```